# How to apply custom css styles to Kendo React Components?

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am developing one project using various kendo react components. I want to customize them as per the requirements. How can override there classes.

can you Provide me any links and references to explore it more.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Kendo React Grid styling examples](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/styling/)

To apply custom CSS styles you can use the className property as shown below to apply the class 'product-name' to in this case, the grid column for ProductName:

```
<GridColumn field="ProductName" title="Product Name" className="product-name">
```